# Macbook Pro Fan is Loud?

Tags: mac, macbook, fan

My Macbook's fan is very loud. When running SMB Fan Control, it says that my fan is faster than usual. The sound is a grinding noise. It happens constantly (about every 20 minutes) and the only way to stop it is to turn it off, or put it on sleep. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fan is making a grinding noise, it's very likely failing.

Send it to Apple for repair.

Comment: make an appointment at the apple store. if they have the fans in stock, they can replace it under warranty in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Macs, but a grinding sound from a fan that happens at regular intervals, that is fixed by resting it sounds very much like heat is expanding a support, causing the fan to hit something else.